# Angular 4 - How to add new quantity with existing cart quantity

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular 4 e-commerce website, In this I want to add item count with the previous cart count.

Assume like there is 5 items in my cart, now I have added another 5 items, now the cart count should be shown as 10.

How can I achieve this.

This is the code I have written.

```
import { Component,EventEmitter,Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SessionStorageService,SessionStorage } from 'angular-web-storage';
import {CartdataService} from '../cartdata.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-cart',
    templateUrl: './my-cart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-cart.component.css'],
    outputs :['ChildEvent']
})
export class MyCartComponent  {
    public counter : number = 1;   

    constructor(private CartdataService :CartdataService,private 
        router:Router,private http: HttpClient) {
            this.router.events.subscribe(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
    }

    increment() { 
        this.counter += 1;
    }

    decrement() {
        if(this.counter >1){
            this.counter -= 1;
        }
    }

    public sendRecord(Totalcartval : number ) {  
        this.CartdataService.editCount(Totalcartval);  
    }
}
```

Here I am sending the cart count to the service. Before sending the cart value I want to add the existing cart count + newly added products count.
Guide me to achieve this

This is my HTML part.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control col-8 text-center bg-white font-weight-bold " id="counterval" value="{{counter}}"
             #Totalcartval>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary text-white" (click)="decrement()" role="button">
            <i class="fa fa-minus" style="font-size:15px"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary text-white" (click)="increment()" role="button">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:15px"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like making an `Observable` service and by using that service in you component.

cart.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
    private totalItems: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    getCartItems() {
        return this.totalItems.asObservable();
    }

    updateCartItems(items: number) {
        this.totalItems.next(items);
    }
}
```

and then in your component using it like

cart.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {CartService} from './cart.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'cart-component',
    template: `
        <div>
        <input type="number" readonly [(ngModel)]="total"/>
        </div>
        <button (click)="increase()">Increase</button>
        <button (click)="decrease()">Decrease</button>
    `
})
export class CartComponent {

    total;

    constructor(private cartService:CartService) {
    }

    increase() {
        this.cartService.updateCartItems(this.total+1);
    }

    decrease() {
        this.cartService.updateCartItems(this.total-1);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cartService.getCartItems()
            .subscribe(value => {
                this.total = value;
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: When I change the value ,the mean time the value is changed in the cart ,But in my case always the cart value is updated only on the button click like "Add to Cart".So how can I change this code and it takes the old cart value along with the new value so the newly added products quantity popup says that the quantity of the new product is the total value .It's confusing

Comment: You can achieve this with the above. You will always get the updated cart count from the service so no need to modify that value in the component. Just use one directional data flow. Here single truth source of data is our service which will always provide you the updated value

Comment: Nice its working fine.When I click add the corresponding product ill be added and it price should be added with previous price,  when I decrease the quantity the price should get subtracts from previous one .Please if possible can you tell me ho to achieve this?

Comment: You can create a property in service for that and update the price based on increase & decrease of the quantity.